# How to check if a range is a part of another range in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

How can I simply check if a range is a subrange of another ?

`range1 in range2` will not work as expected.

Answer (score 22):

You can do it in `O(1)`, as follows:

```
def range_subset(range1, range2):
    """Whether range1 is a subset of range2."""
    if not range1:
        return True  # empty range is subset of anything
    if not range2:
        return False  # non-empty range can't be subset of empty range
    if len(range1) > 1 and range1.step % range2.step:
        return False  # must have a single value or integer multiple step
    return range1.start in range2 and range1[-1] in range2
```

In use:

```
>>> range_subset(range(0, 1), range(0, 4))
True
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroH.G code isn't really readable in comments, why not post a new answer? Note you could also write a new function `range_overlap` as simply returning `range_subset(r1, r2) or range_subset(r2, r1)`, which would have the advantage of lazy evaluation (if `r1` _is_ a subset of `r2`, it doesn't bother to check whether or not `r2` is a subset of `r1`).

Answer (score 4):

`set((range(0,1))).issubset(range(0,4))` will do it.

Comment: This works but is potentially inefficient for large ranges. For example, a range that's a million integers long will have to construct a set that contains a million items.

Answer (score 4):

I was working on a similar problem: how to find if two ranges overlap. Hence, the order of ranges introduced in the function was a limitation for me (the order should not affect). This is the solution I propose (inspired by [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) answer):

```
def range_overlap(range1, range2):
  """Whether range1 and range2 overlap."""
  x1, x2 = range1.start, range1.stop
  y1, y2 = range2.start, range2.stop
  return x1 <= y2 and y1 <= x2
```

```
a = range(20, 25, 2)
b = range(23, 25, 3) # different step does not matter
print(list(a), list(b)) # [20, 22, 24] [23]
range_overlap(a, b) # True
```

In case any range is empty:

```
# if range1 is non-empty and range2 is empty
a = range(20, 25, 1)
b = range(22, 22, 3) # empty but the range start and end overlap

assert range_overlap(a, b) == range_overlap(a, b)
range_overlap(a, b)
# True
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the most readable imo, but inefficient:

```
all(e in range2 for e in range1)
```

I think this would be the most efficient if both ranges have the same step:

```
range1[0] in range2 and range1[-1] in range2
```

Comment: First one looks fine, but the second one might fail if the ranges have steps other than 1. Ex. `range(0,9,3)` and `range(0,8,2)`

Comment: The efficient version can break if the step in range1 is coprime to range2.  Consider `range(0,15,5)` and `range(0,12,2)`

Comment: And to add to the above - also if the step in `range2` is larger than that in `range1`, regardless of coprimality.

Comment: both work for `xrange` too, and `xrange` doesn't provide `.step` (or any) methods. the variant `any(...)` can be used to check for intersection without subsection. and talking about the efficiency of large sets while using `range` is just silly.

Comment: watch out for inputs like `range(1, 1)` -> `range(2, 4).` Depending on the range you compare, this can become `all([])` -> `True`. `all(e in range(2, 4) for e in range(1, 1))` evaluates as `True`